# Stability of critical points of a system given by a constant matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, lyapunov-functions

We are given the homogeneous system 
$$y'=\begin{bmatrix}5 & -3 & 2 \\ 15 & -9 & 6 \\ 10 & -6 & 4\end{bmatrix}y$$
with the initial value $y(0)=(1,1,0)$
and are supposed to check whether the critical points are (asymptotically) stable.

I tried to directly apply the formal definitions of stability but failed to arrive at something useful.

Is this a use case for Lyapunov? If so how do I find an explicit Lyapunov function? Lyapunov has only just been introduced and I can't find any examples for a case as simple as this. Most use some physical intuition about energy...

Comment: Did you notice that the second and third lines are multiplies of the first one? So it cannot be asymptotically stable. It is less immediate that it is unstable.

Comment: @JohnB yes, thanks, I have already solved a corresponding inhomogeneous system using that fact. But how do you deduce stability properties from the fact that the kernel is a plane?(it is intuitively clear)

Comment: Confirmed, getting all zero eigenvalues here. A simulation shows trajectories running off to infinity, so I doubt there's a Lyapunov function here? Not entirely sure though.

Comment: The answer is always the same: Jordan canonical form. It determines the stability. What happens is that in this case the Jordan form is not diagonal, so there is something above the diagonal making some trajectories move away from the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth practicing Jordan normal form, especially when they give you something where all numbers are integers, with the possible exception of a denominator needed for the inverse matrix. That is, I am constructing $P^{-1}A P = J,$ where your coefficient matrix is called $A.$ The minimal polynomial is $x^2,$ so there will be a 2 by2 block and a singleton. We start with the right hand column, calling it $w,$ where the only requirement is that $w$ not itself be an eigenvector. I like 
$$
w =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
For the middle column, we are required to take $v = A w,$ so
$$
v =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2 \\
6 \\
4
\end{array}
\right)
$$

For the left hand column, any eigenvector not a multiple of $v$ is acceptable, and I like
$$
u =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
2 \\
3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
for
$$
P =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 2&0  \\
2 & 6 & 0  \\
3 & 4 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Next
$$
P^{-1} =
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-3 & 1&0  \\
1 & 0 & 0  \\
5 & -3 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and we have $P^{-1}A P = J,$ with
$$
J =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0&0  \\
0 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The reason for finding actual matrices $P$ and $P^{-1}$ is simply that you get explicit
$$  P J P^{-1} = A $$
It is from that  expression that we can find explicit $e^A$ and $e^At$

Comment: Alternatively, if $A^2=0$, then $e^A=I+A$ and $e^{tA}=I+tA$.

Comment: @amd good point.